# Image map doesn't work in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I really tried everything but it just doesn't work.

Code is

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Map test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <img usemap="#map1" src="/assets/templates/design01/header2.jpg" alt="SaveMe Header" />
  <map name="map1">
    <a href="/sitemap" shape="rect" coords="600,115,670,135" title="Sitemap"></a>
    <a href="/contact" shape="rect" coords="680,115,750,135" title="Contact"></a>
  </map>
</body>
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me in chrome.

Comment: It might seem prude of me, but please keep the profanity out of your posts. =)

Comment: Also - don't you specify imagemaps with `area` (not `a`), instead? Forgive me for posting w3schools, but their example works: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp

Comment: @J.Steen Post that comment as an answer.. I was writing up an answer already, but you got it first, and I don't want to seem as if I was simply copying you.

Comment: @Daedalus I was already writing an answer as well. Sorry to steal your thunder with a comment. =)

Comment: @J.Steen It's alright.

Comment: I am such a idiot. Now I feel ashamed. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your `a` tags to `area`, it'll work.

```
<map name="map1">
  <area href="/sitemap" shape="rect" coords="600,115,670,135" title="Sitemap"></area>
  <area href="/contact" shape="rect" coords="680,115,750,135" title="Contact"></area>
</map>
```